# Docker ELK multiline exception stack trace

Tags: docker, devops

Hay guys,

I am Using **ELK**(spujadas/elk-docker) with help of **logspout**(gliderlabs/logspout).
Problem is ELK is not printing multiline exception stack trace in kibana.

I want entire stack trace to be ingested as a single message like this.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Something bad happened    
at com.example.myproject.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilter(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.example.myproject.ExceptionHandlerFilter.doFilter(ExceptionHandlerFilter.java:28)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
```

I need help!

Answer (score 0):

there exist an Elastic Plugin
Here is the link [Multiline Codec Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html)
I hope this is what you searched for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the multiline plugin of logstash, need to edit logstash config, the following is example:

```
file {
  path => "xxx.log"
  ignore_older => 0
  type => "type_of_log"
  codec => multiline {
    pattern => "^%{YEAR}[./-]%{MONTHNUM}[./-]%{MONTHDAY}"
    negate => true
    what => "previous"
    auto_flush_interval => 1
  }
}
```